# Can the null set be an element of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The cartesian product, $\{\varnothing\} \times \{\text{piano, flute}\}$, gives:

$\{(\varnothing,\text{piano}),(\varnothing,\text{flute})\}$.

But if, in $(a,b)$, either a or b $= \varnothing$, then the pair $= \varnothing$.

So product is really $\{\varnothing, \varnothing\}$ or **$\mathbb{\{\varnothing\}}$**. Am I correct that this product is different from $\varnothing$, meaning that a set containing $\varnothing$ is different from $\varnothing$ alone?

Comment: I don't understand why you say that if $a$ or $b$ is $\emptyset$ then $(a,b)$ is $\emptyset$. This is simply not true in any encoding of an ordered pair. (The "standard" encoding is $\{ a,\{ a,b \} \}$.) Is it possible you mean the product of $\emptyset$ itself with a set? That is indeed empty, regardless of what the other set is.

Comment: No, $(\varnothing, \text{piano}) \ne \varnothing$.

Comment: @Ian I thought the standard encoding was $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}.$

Comment: @bof You're right, I forgot about that distinction. That approach doesn't need an application of foundation to ensure that it actually works correctly, which is a modest benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, indeed: $\big\{\{\}\big\}\times \big\{a,\{\}\big\} = \big\{(\{\}, a), (\{\}, \{\})\big\}$ and neither *pair* is an empty set, nor is the Cartesian product empty.

Where as: $\big\{\big\}\times\big\{a,\{\}\big\} = \big\{\big\}$

The empty set by itself is not the same thing as a construct containing the empty set.

$$\{\varnothing\}\neq \varnothing\\ (\varnothing, x)\neq \varnothing$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the null set can be an element of a set.

You are correct that a set containing $\varnothing$ is different from $\varnothing$ alone; for example: $\{\varnothing\} \ne \varnothing$. Or as a concrete example, the latter is equivalent to an empty baggie, while the former is a [baggie containing an empty baggie](http://www.madmath.com/2010/04/sets-as-plastic-baggies.html).

But it is incorrect to say that "if, in $(a,b)$, either $a$ or $b$ $= \varnothing$, then the pair $= \varnothing$"; that's simply not true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For each set $X$, we have $\emptyset \in P(X)$, the power set of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that when you wrote

> if, in $(a,b)$, either $a$ or $b=\varnothing$, then the pair $=\varnothing$

you may have actually had in mind the following statement, which (unlike the quote above) is actually true:

> If, in $a \times b$, either $a$ or $b=\varnothing$, then the Cartesian product $=\varnothing$

If I am right -- if that is actually what you meant -- than I suspect you are having trouble distinguishing in a consistent way between the *members* of a set and the *set itself*.  $a \times b$ is not an ordered pair, but a *collection* of ordered pairs, each of the form $(x,y)$ where $x\in a$ and $y\in b$.  If $a$ has no elements, that is if $a=\varnothing$, then you can't form any ordered pairs whose first member is an *element* of $a$.  But you can still form an ordered pair whose first element is $a$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is an element of the set of subsets of every set.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Example